# for loops within dictionaries vs dictionaries within for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

Hi I have a question about iterating through a list and adding items and their frequency within the list to a dictionary.

```
i = ['apple','pear','red','apple','red','red','pear','pear','pear']
d = {x:i.count(x) for x in i} 
print (d)
```

outputs

```
{'pear': 4, 'apple': 2, 'red': 3}
```

However

```
i = ['apple','pear','red','apple','red','red','pear', 'pear', 'pear']
d = {} 
for x in i: 
    d={x:i.count(x)}
print(d)
```

outputs

```
{'pear': 4}
```

I need to iterate through the list while adding each iteration within the dictionary to a new list. However I can't understand why the two different codes are giving different results.

It's encouraging to seee that the count function works on the second one. But I am confused as to where apple and red dissapeared to.

Sorry for bad wording etcetera been working on this hours and is driving me crazy. Thanks so much for taking time to help

I am confused as to why the two results are different

Comment: The answers already give great insight. Just to rephrase this for whoever finds it helpful. In the first code block, you are giving the instruction "add this key:pair to the dictionary `d`". In the loop, you are giving the instruction: "Assign this dictionary with key:pair to a variable called `d`".  Since the loop assigns it multiple times, only the last assignment remains.

Comment: Also, none of the answers address the big problem with even your first code: `i.count(x)` iterates over _all_ elements in the `i` list. Running it for each `x` in `i` means your code is O(n^2). You could have just iterated over the list, and `d[x] += 1` for each `x` in `i`, and your code would have been O(n). Or, just use `collections.Counter`, which does the same thing (one answer recommends this, but doesn't explain why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you must add `key:value` pairs in the second loop instead of overwriting `d` with every loop.

```py
i = ['apple','pear','red','apple','red','red','pear','pear','pear']
d = {}

for x in i:
    d[x] = i.count(x)

print(d)
```

will output the same as your first function.

```
{'pear': 4, 'apple': 2, 'red': 3}
```

Basically in your second example when you do `d={x:i.count(x)}` you have a one element dictionary and for every loop you overwrite that. Then it only shows `pear: 4` because `pear` is the last element in your `i` list.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = ['apple','pear','red','apple','red','red','pear', 'pear', 'pear']
d = {} 
log = []
for x in i: 
    log.append({x:i.count(x)})
```

`log` is

```
[{'apple': 2},
 {'pear': 4},
 {'red': 3},
 {'apple': 2},
 {'red': 3},
 {'red': 3},
 {'pear': 4},
 {'pear': 4},
 {'pear': 4}]
```

Comment: This does not do what is trying to be accomplished. It will give a `list` instead of a `dict` like the OP created.

Comment: Question asker was 'confused as to why the two results are different', instead of getting `dict`

Comment: And your answer doesn't answer that question.

Comment: I think question asker upvoted my answer tho

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your first bit of code and it gave me

```
{'apple': 2, 'pear': 4, 'red': 3}
```

which is correct but differs from what you've stated in the question.

To address your second bit of code, you're performing assignment operation on each iteration of the loop, so the value of `d` is being re-written every time you access a new item of `i`

Personally I would recommend using Counter for this problem:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> z = ['blue', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red']
>>> Counter(z)
Counter({'blue': 3, 'red': 2, 'yellow': 1})
```

Comment: The reason that it gave you a different output is because dictionaries are unordered and will print in any random order. The output you got was perfectly correct and normal.

Comment: Dictionaries have been insertion-ordered since Python 3.7. https://stackoverflow.com/q/39980323/843953 @user99999

Comment: I originally meant the difference to be in the "pear" count @user99999, but OP corrected that in the question. The answer you gave is correct though )

Answer (score -1):

```
varLs = ['apple','pear','red','apple','red','red','pear','pear','pear']

def frequency(varLs):  
    counters = {}

    for item in varLs:
        if item not in counters:
            counters[item] = 1
        else:
            counters[item]+= 1
    return counters

print(frequency(varLs))
```

returns {'apple': 2, 'pear': 4, 'red': 3}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).